# Angularjs - Generate a secure read only view or editable view

Tags: angularjs, security

I've been searching but i might have been looking for the wrong terms.
Anyway, what i want to do is generate different elements based on if the user is authorized or not (read-only mode).

For example, if the user is not authorize i want to generate a label with the data. If instead the user is authorized i want to generate a textbox / textarea etc.. that they can edit. Are there any built in directives for this type of generation or do i need to create a custom directive?

Looking at angulars site, http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly
It almost has the functionality except that i want to switch the textbox to a label instead.

A note on security, the users should not be able to change an attribute in the html to activate the control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ng-if`

i.e.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-if='user.admin' ng-model="myModel" />
    <span ng-if='!user.admin'>{{ myModel }}</span>
</div>
```

It requires a bit more html. If there is another way I would love to hear about it because I use `ng-if` in my companies role-based order system I wrote.

---

**Edit**

Okay, so I wrote a quick little Directive that still needs some more work.

The HTML (Please note: there are no {{ curly braces }} for scope objects):

```
<auth-input can-edit="admin" obj="input" model="authTest" obj-class="form-control" type="text">
</auth-input>
```

> **can-edit** - admin (boolean) is coming from the scope, i.e. `$scope.admin=true;` Using {{ admin }} will throw an error.
>   **obj** - The type of object you want if admin = true (currently only supports input and textarea).
>   **model** - reference to the ng-model you want to bind to.
>   **obj-class** - The class attribute, in case you are using a framework like bootstrap, foundation, etc.

Current Input element supported attributes (more need to be supported):

- type
- id

Directive:

```
angular.module('authInputs', []).directive('authInput', function ($compile) {
    var inputTemplate = '';
    var textTemplate = '';
    var textareaTemplate = '';

    var getTemplate = function (objType, editable) {
        var template = '';
        switch (objType) {
            case 'input':
                template = (editable) ? inputTemplate : textTemplate;
                break;
            case 'textarea':
                template = (editable) ? textareaTemplate : textTemplate;
                break;
        }
        return template;
    };

    var setupTemplates = function (attrs) {
        // Need to build in more flexibility for other input tags, and make this part better.
        // Will eventually have an array of accepted attribute names and if attrs contains a matching key
        // then inject it by building the input element in the for (var k in attrs) loop.
        // Also need to do the same for other element types.
        inputTemplate = (attrs.id) ? '<input type="' + attrs.type + '" id="' + attrs.id + '" ng-model="model" class="' + attrs.objClass + '" />' : '<input type="' + attrs.type + '" ng-model="model" class="' + attrs.objClass + '" />';
        textareaTemplate = (attrs.id) ? '<textarea ng-model="model" id="' + attrs.id + '" class="' + attrs.objClass + '">{{ model }}</textarea>' : '<textarea ng-model="model" class="' + attrs.objClass + '">{{ model }}</textarea>';
        textTemplate = '{{ model }}';
    };

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            setupTemplates(attrs);
            scope.$watch('watch', function () {
                element.html(getTemplate(attrs.obj, Boolean(scope.$parent[attrs.canEdit])));
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        },
        scope: {
            model: '=model',
            watch: '=canEdit'
        }
    };
});
```

Then just inject it as you would other modules:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['authInputs']);
```

Feel free to make it better, I have a lot more to do with it but little time at the moment. I will try to spend some time on it soon and update this answer and my fiddle link.

<kbd>[Demo with binding and toggle](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/83Qbv/4/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the information, sounds like a good first step. Might look into creating a separate directive later on.

Comment: Yeah I think I am going to do that as well for my projects. If I make one I'll edit this answer and add the code, probably wont happen very soon though.

Comment: @user2203542 I have made a VERY simple directive that you could use, it needs a little bit more work and probably some fine tuning, but I can post it here if you would like.

Comment: That would definately be interresting!.

Comment: @user2203542 Just updated my answer with the information and a fiddle link. There is still plenty more for me to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The AngularFire Seed uses NG-Show-Auth (located here: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/index.html) to determine visibility of elementes, not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Once you decide to use that you could *maybe* use a (my brain is slipping on the name at the moment) but a custom HTML element I.E.

```
<name></name>
```

and then in the text for the custom element, it will contain both the ng-show-auth true and false cases.

```
<input ng-show-auth=true></input>
<p ng-show-auth=false>{{text}}</p>
```

This will allow you to read the code a little easier (when you're reviewing it) and keep that particular implementation (sort of) out of the actual HTML.

Comment: This is very interesting, I will have to look into this myself. And I think the word you are looking for is `Directive`? :)

Comment: I think you're right, the first example on the site here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive was something like <div mydirective> </div> and I got confused (I had originally thought it was a directive), later on in the docs it talks about <my-customer> or something so you're right.